# Merge and synonymize: [photoshop-script] to [photoshop]

Tags: discussion, tags, synonym-request

I propose that those tags gets merged and synonymized. [photoshop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/photoshop) has more questions than [photoshop-script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/photoshop-script) (almost 2456 versus 639 total, with 391 questions sharing both tags), and more info on it's page, so I suggest it becomes the main tag (although I'm not sure if those criteria matter in this case).

I've seen a recent question posted with both tags (not linking due to meta effect, but id is `73722372`) and it seemed odd, because I thought *"given the nature of Stack Overflow, what would be on-topic for [photoshop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/photoshop) but off-topic for [photoshop-script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/photoshop-script)?"*. So, I went into each tag page, and here are their respective info card (with emphasis mine):

> [photoshop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/photoshop)
>
> **For questions strictly about photoshop scripting!** Photoshop is a raster graphics editor by Adobe Systems, that is industry standard for creating, modifying and treating images and graphics. It has plugins and scripts that can be installed on top, in order to automate and add further functionality. If you're not scripting for Photoshop, then your question belongs on Super User, Photography, or Graphic Design.

and

> [photoshop-script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/photoshop-script)
>
> Photoshop script can automate a series of tasks or manipulate images from within Photoshop. Photoshop scripts can written in AppleScript, JavaScript or VBScript. (The latter is not well supported)

So it seems like the answer to my indagation is: *Nothing.* (on-topic for [photoshop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/photoshop) but off-topic for [photoshop-script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/photoshop-script)). Hence, the proposal to merge those tags.

Comment: I see at least a couple Python questions that are on-topic, about Photoshop, but not about Photoshop Script.